# Vue - Component abstraction and inheritance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a Vue application that allows users to create quizzes made up of different types of questions. I have multiple choice questions (both single selection/radio button and multiple selection/checkbox), open answer, attachment answer, so on and so forth.

I'm looking to create a generic `Question` component that will display the correct type of input (text editor, radio buttons, file input, etc.) depending on the type of question.

Let's assume I am using TS and I have a `Question` interface with a field `questionType` that easily allows differentiating among the types of questions.

The solution I've come up with is the following:

I have an `AbstractQuestion` component that defines the general template of the questions, i.e. there's a slot for displaying the question text and one for the inputs.

Then, for each type of question, there's a component, e.g. `OpenAnswerQuestion`, in whose template there is an `AbstractQuestion` with the slots filled with the correct template parts. Finally, I expose to the rest of the app a `Question` component that uses `<component :is="...">` to dynamically display the correct question type.

AbstractQuestion.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <slot name="questionText">
      <p v-html="exercise.text" />
    </slot>

    <!-- contains the input controls to answer the question
    (e.g. checkboxes, textareas...) -->
    <slot
      v-if="!readOnly || !$slots.readOnlyAnswer?.()"
      name="submissionControls"
    ></slot>

    <!-- representation of a read-only answer given to the question (e.g. a code fragment for a programming exercise) -->
    <slot v-else name="readOnlyAnswer"></slot>

    <slot name="solution"></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, PropType } from "@vue/runtime-core";
export default defineComponent({
  name: "AbstractQuestion",
  props: {
    question: {
      type: Object as PropType<Question>,
      required: true,
    },
    readOnly: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

Example of an "inheriting" question type:

OpenAnswerQuestion.vue

```
<template>
  <AbstractQuestion v-bind="$props">
    <template #submissionControls>
      <TextEditor
        :disabled="readOnly"
        v-model="answerTextProxy"
      />
    </template>

    <template #readOnlyAnswer>
        <p
          v-html="answerTextProxy"
        />
    </template>
  </AbstractQuestion>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, PropType } from "@vue/runtime-core";
import TextEditor from "@/components/ui/TextEditor.vue";
import AbstractExercise from "./AbstractQuestion.vue";
export default defineComponent({
  name: "OpenAnswerQuestion",
  props: {
    question: {
      type: Object as PropType<Question>,
      required: true,
    },
    answer: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
    readOnly: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  methods: {},
  computed: {
    answerTextProxy: {
      get() {
        return this.answer;
      },
      set(val: string) {
        this.$emit("updateAnswerText", val);
      },
    },
  },
  components: { TextEditor, AbstractQuestion },
});
</script>
```

And the component actually exposed:
Question.vue

```
<template>
  <component :is="questionComponentName" v-bind="$props"></component>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, PropType } from "@vue/runtime-core";
export default defineComponent({
  name: "Question",
  props: {
    question: {
      type: Object as PropType<Question>,
      required: true,
    },
    readOnly: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  methods: {},
  computed: {
    questionComponentName(): string {
      const componentNames: Record<QuestionType, string> = {
        [QuestionType.OPEN_ANSWER]: "OpenAnswerQuestion",
        // ... rest of the mapping
      };
      return componentNames[this.question.questionType];
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

This seems to be working, but it feels kinda hacky. Is there a better way to achieve this specialization/dynamic dispatch/abstraction of components in Vue3?

Comment: Given that the code is workable, probably the question for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com . It looks ok. AbstractQuestion looks useless abstraction in its current state, maybe it's justified if there's a need for more common code

Comment: The reason I didn't post this to the sw engineering SE is that I was looking for a vue-specific idiomatic way of doing this, so this had more to do with code than abstract engineering. I find AbstractQuestion to be useful because there are a lot of component that need to display questions regardless of their type. Questions need to be interchangeable to other components and I didn't want all my app to constantly have to use a cascade of v-if's to distinguish among question types. You think it's superfluous?

Comment: I meant AbstractQuestion.vue, while you seem to describe the usage of  Question.vue. I don't see how it affects the way questions are used. Without AbstractQuestion.vue it would be the same with dynamic <component> and no v-if. If there's a considerable amount of reusable template logic or layout then AbstractQuestion.vue is justified, otherwise it's just a shallow wrapper. As for reusable non-template logic, it can be stored in composition functions

Comment: Apologies, I misread your comment. You're correct, I was talking about Question.vue. 
I am just keeping that wrapper because having an additional layer of indirection could make future extensions a bit easier, but yeah that's probably not necessary.

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I do in this situation.